# preg_replace PHP not working?

Tags: php, preg-replace

Why doesn't preg_replace return anything in this scenario? I've been trying to figure it out all night.

**Here is the text contained within $postContent:**

Test this. Here is a quote: [Quote]1[/Quote] Quote is now over.

**Here is my code:**

```
echo "Test I'm Here!!!";
                    $startQuotePos = strpos($postContent,'[Quote]')+7;
                    $endQuotePos = strpos($postContent,'[/Quote]');
                    $postStrLength = strlen($postContent);
                    $quotePostID = substr($postContent,$startQuotePos,($endQuotePos-$postStrLength));
                    $quotePattern = '[Quote]'.$quotePostID.'[/Quote]';
                    $newPCAQ = preg_replace($quotePattern,$quotePostID,$postContent);
                    echo "<br />$startQuotePos<br />$endQuotePos<br />$quotePostID<br />Qpattern:$quotePattern<br />PCAQ: $newPCAQ<br />";
```

**This is my results:**

Test I'm Here!!!

35

36

1

Qpattern:[Quote]1[/Quote]

PCAQ:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `preg_replace()`, `"[Quote]"` matches a single character that is one of the following: *q*, *u*, *o*, *t*, or *e*.

If you want that `preg_replace()` finds the literal `"[Quote]"`, you need to escape it as `"\[Quote\]"`. [preg_quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) is the function you should use: `preg_quote("[Quote]")`.

Your code is also wrong because a regular expression is expected to start with a delimiter. In the `preg_replace()` call I am showing at the end of my answer, that is *@*, but you could use another character, as long as it doesn't appear in the regular expression, and it is used also at the end of the regular expression. (In my case, *@* is followed by a pattern modifier, and pattern modifiers are the only characters allowed after the pattern delimiter.)

If you are going to use `preg_replace()`, it doesn't make sense that you first find where `"[Quote]"` is. I would rather use the following code:

```
$newPCAQ = preg_replace('@\[Quote\](.+?)\[/Quote\]@i', '\1', $postContent);
```

I will explain the regular expression I am using:

- The final `'@i'` is saying to `preg_replace()` to ignore the difference between lowercase, and uppercase characters; the string could contain `"[QuOte]234[/QuOTE]"`, and that substring would match the regular expression the same.
- I use a question mark in `"(.+?)"` to avoid `".+"` is too greedy, and matches too much characters. without it, the regular expression could include in a single match a substring like `"[Quote]234[/Quote] Other text [Quote]475[/Quote]"` while this should be matched as two substrings: `"[Quote]234[/Quote]"`, and `"[Quote]475[/Quote]"`.
- The `'\1'` string I am using as replacement string is saying to `preg_replace()` to use the string matched from the sub-group `"(.+?)"` as replacement. In other words, the call to `preg_replace()` is removing `"[Quote]"`, and `"[/Quote]"` surrounding other text. (It doesn't replace `"[/Quote]"` that doesn't match with `"[Quote]"`, such as in `"[/Quote] Other text [Quote]"`.)

Answer (score 2):

your regex must start & end with '/':

```
$quotePattern = '/[Quote]'.$quotePostID.'[/Quote]/';
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I really need to work on my understanding of regex. For now str_ireplace works for me. Is either of these (str_ireplace vs. preg_replace) more efficient than the other?

Comment: i did a little research, it looks like str_replace is slightly faster for simple string substitutions such as yours. but i doubt it is anything to worry about, since the difference is so minuscule.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't see anything for the return value of [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg-replace) is because it has returned `NULL` (*see the manual link for details*). This is what preg_replace returns when an error occurs, which is what happened in your situation. The string value of `NULL` is a **zero-length string**. You can see this by using [var_dump](http://php.net/var-dump) instead, which will tell you that preg_replace returned NULL.

Your regular expression is invalid and as such PHP will throw an `E_WARNING` level error of `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '['`

There are a couple of reason for this. First, you need to specify an opening and closing delimiter for you regular expression as preg_* functions use [PCRE style](http://php.net/pcre) regular expression. Second, you want to also consider using [preg_quote](http://php.net/preg-quote) on your patter (*sans the delimiter*) to ensure it is escaped properly.

```
$postContent = "Test this. Here is a quote: [Quote]1[/Quote] Quote is now over.";
/* Specify a delimiter for your regular expression */
$delimiter = '@';

$startQuotePos = strpos($postContent,'[Quote]')+7;
$endQuotePos = strpos($postContent,'[/Quote]');
$postStrLength = strlen($postContent);
$quotePostID = substr($postContent,$startQuotePos,($endQuotePos-$postStrLength));
/* Make sure you use the delimiter in your pattern and escape it properly */
$quotePattern = $delimiter . preg_quote("[Quote]{$quotePostID}[/Quote]", $delimiter) . $delimiter;
$newPCAQ = preg_replace($quotePattern,$quotePostID,$postContent);
echo "<br />$startQuotePos<br />$endQuotePos<br />$quotePostID<br />Qpattern:$quotePattern<br />PCAQ: $newPCAQ<br />";
```

**The output will be:**

35

36

1

Qpattern:@[Quote]1[/Quote]@

PCAQ: Test this. Here is a quote: 1 Quote is now over.